# Deleting cells if they contain 0

Tags: excel, vba

Im looking to delete certain cells in all the columns on my worksheet if they contain 0 and then shift all the data upwards.

I found this formula on a different thread and it only worked for one column (column p) for some reason and only worked on half of that.

Hope you experts can help.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim row_index As Long, lRow As Long, i As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim delRange As Range

    '~~> Change this to the relevant worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    row_index = 7

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With ws
        lRow = .Range("P" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        For i = row_index To lRow
            If .Range("P" & i).Value <> "" And .Range("P" & i).Value = 0 Then
                If delRange Is Nothing Then
                    Set delRange = .Range("P" & i)
                Else
                    Set delRange = Union(delRange, .Range("P" & i))
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End With

    If Not delRange Is Nothing Then delRange.Delete shift:=xlUp
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: To clarify, I do not want to delete any rows or columns, I just want to delete the actual cell and then shift them up

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code.  The problem looks to be that your actual delete command is not in the loop, but at the end.  So it only happens once.  Also, Union() is unnecessary.

```
Sub Sample()

Dim lRow, i As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim delRange As Range
'~~> Change this to the relevant worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

With ws
    lRow = .Range("P" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = lRow To 7 Step -1
        If .Range("P" & i).Value <> "" And .Range("P" & i).Value = 0 Then
            .Range("P" & i).Delete shift:=xlUp
        End If
    Next
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

What is up with .delete of a unioned range...?
[image: The range...]
[image: What gets deleted...]

Comment: Excel told me there was an error in this line      Set delRange = Union(delRange, .Range("P" & i))

Comment: I have edited it since I posted.  You were to fast!  Union is not appropriate as the .delete of a unioned range is not working.  Not sure why honestly.

Comment: Reversed the loop to start at the bottom of the sheet.  Much more efficient code now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub ZeroKiller()
    Dim rKill As Range
    Set rKill = Nothing
    For Each r In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        If r.Value = 0 And r.Value <> "" Then
            If rKill Is Nothing Then
                Set rKill = r
            Else
                Set rKill = Union(rKill, r)
            End If
        End If
    Next r

    If rKill Is Nothing Then
    Else
    rKill.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This mad my worksheet freeze. Probably my computers fault but for now its nor working

Comment: Even if it says not responding still? how long should I give it before I restart/try again

Comment: Gary's formula worked perfect! It just took forever! thanks so much!

Comment: You are quite welcome.  **This type of macro can be "quickened" if you are going to use it frequently.**